# PHP data in AJAX success?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to run a very basic PHP code via AJAX and get the data back from PHP page into AJAX success.

however, I don't get anything in the AJAX success from the PHP page and its bugging me badly.

this is the AJAX code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(function(){
    $('#form-post').on('submit', function(e){

        // prevent native form submission here
        e.preventDefault();

        // now do whatever you want here
        $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr('method'), // <-- get method of form
            url: $(this).attr('action'), // <-- get action of form
            data: $(this).serialize(), // <-- serialize all fields into a string that is ready to be posted to your PHP file
            beforeSend: function(){
                //$('#result').html('<img src="loading.gif" />');
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('#messageme').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
});
```

and this is the Form:

```
    <form id="form-post"  action="post-code.php" method="post" >
<input type="hidden" value="Post" name="submit" />
<input type="text" class="inp-form" name="postcode" id="postcode" placeholder="Enter Post Code " /><br  /><br  /><input type="text" id="messageme"  /><br  /><br  />
<input id="findAd" type="button" value=" Search For Address"  />
</form>
```

and a very simple php:

```
<?php

$street = "some";
    echo $street;
?>
```

could someone please advise on this?

Comment: try this $('#messageme').val(data);

Comment: add dataType: 'html'

Comment: @AVM, no, unfortunately I don't get anything!

Comment: And so how do you debug it? You have to learn how to debug it client side and server side. Is the submit handler fired? Is the success callback called? What about error callback? What about URL path? Have you check your network tab? Etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this: just change `type="button"` to `type="submit"`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form-post"  action="post-code.php" method="post" >
<input type="hidden" value="Post" name="submit" />
<input type="text" class="inp-form" name="postcode" id="postcode" placeholder="Enter Post Code " /><br  /><br  />
<input type="text" id="messageme"  /><br  /><br  />
<input id="findAd" type="submit" value=" Search For Address"  />
</form>
<script>$(document).ready(function(){

$(function(){
$('#form-post').on('submit', function(e){

    // prevent native form submission here
    e.preventDefault();

    // now do whatever you want here
    $.ajax({
        type: $(this).attr('method'), // <-- get method of form
        url: $(this).attr('action'), // <-- get action of form
        data: $(this).serialize(), // <-- serialize all fields into a string that is ready to be posted to your PHP file
        beforeSend: function(){
            //$('#result').html('<img src="loading.gif" />');
        },
        success: function(data){
             alert(data);
            $('#messageme').html(data);
        }
        });
        });
        });
        });
    </script>


    </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Wait, that looks obvious now... ;)

Comment: OMG, i've been trying to figure this out for the past 2 hours and it was that simple. Thanks bud.

Comment: @Priyank, I did try to upvote it buddy but it says I need to have 15 reputation to upvote an answer! but I accepted your answer. :)

Comment: @william :hey now you can upvote my answer,now your reputation is more than 15.so please upvote :)

Comment: thanx dear & happy new yr in advance :)